# how can I perform interpolation in I18n locales?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
en:
  welcome:
    hello there, #{current_user.first_name}!  It's nice to see you again.
```

That obviously won't work, and apparently "#{" is invalid characters in yaml, because that string shows up as just "hello there, " when I pull it out.

The best I could do was something like:

```
en:
  welcome:
    hello there, (name)!  It's nice to see you again.

....

t(:welcome).gsub("(name)", current_user.first_name)
```

But I am not crazy about that...  There must be a better way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Replace your en.yml like this

```
en:
  welcome:
    "hello there, %{name}!  It's nice to see you again."
```

and your view like this

```
<%=t(:welcome, :name=> current_user.first_name) %>
```

Basically it is passed as a named argument. You can find more at [Rails Guides 18n Interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation)